# One item select not working on radio buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and filter option. When I select an item in radio buttons, its getting right data.

```
<input ng-click="filter = !filter" ng-value="!filter" ng-checked="filter" type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.filter[category]" />
```

But I need allow one select in radio buttons and its not working. What's the problem? Thanks.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tgp33x0a/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

To properly work, radio inputs need a `name` attribute. It should be the same for all radio of the groupe.

You also need to change the `ng-model` of the radio to store its `value` in a single property.

```
<input ng-click="filter = !filter" ng-value="category" name="wineCategory" ng-checked="filter" type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.filter" />
```

Finally you need to adapt your filter methods.

Answer (score 0):

All the inputs in the Radio box group must have only one reference to an ng-model which is typically the value of the input.

So, your input markup would be

```
      <input value="{{category}}" type="radio" ng-model="ctrl.filterCategory" />
```

Where the value = category would be red, while or champagne.

Now likewise your filter function would change to use the ng-model like this

```
  function filterByCategory(wine) {
    return (self.filterCategory === wine.category || self.filterCategory === "") ? 'show':'hide';
  }
```

Working demo here.

http://jsfiddle.net/nah42h1c/2/